# Назначение события массиву элементов на нативном JS

Tags: javascript

Как назначить событие массиву элементов, наподобие того, как это реализовано в JQuery. Смотри код

```js
$('.variant').click(function() {
  console.log('JQuery', this);
});
// Работает если выбрать конкретный элемент
let variant = document.getElementsByClassName('variant');
variant[0].onmousedown = function() {
  console.log('Native JS', this);
};
// Не работает
variant.onmousedown = function() {
  console.log('Native JS', this);
};
```

```css
.variant {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class='variant'>Текст1</li>
  <li class='variant'>Текст2</li>
  <li class='variant'>Текст3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: в цикле, конечно же, в цикле

Comment: А без цикла нет вариантов?

Comment: А ты думаешь внутри Jquery что? чистая магия?)

Comment: вот файл https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js ..... включи поиск по `while ( t-- ) {` и в теле этого цикла увидишь `elem.addEventListener( type, eventHandle );`...... Понимаешь в чем магия?))

Comment: "Эх, Митрофанова! Такого дяди племянница!" - Добро пожаловать, или Посторонним вход воспрещён

Comment: Перевожу: "Эх, @Igor! Такого меня тезка!"